# Azure SQL Server : Cannot drop the external data source because it is being used

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, bulkinsert

I am trying to import data into Azure SqlServer using OPENROWSET from a file which was uploaded into Azure Storage
I basically do the same flow as given example of Microsoft in here :

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<password>';

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ElasticDBQueryCred  
WITH IDENTITY = '<username>',
SECRET = '<password>';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc 
WITH (
    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'Azure Storage URL',
    CREDENTIAL = ElasticDBQueryCred
);
```

since my secret was set to valid only within 1 days, each time my batch running, I will try to drop and recreate everything from ETERNAL DATA SOURCE to MASTER KEY

Everything seems to run fine until suddenly one of my created EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE cannot be drop by the error :

> Cannot drop the external data source 'xxx' because it is being used.

which is causing my CREDENTIAL also be stuck, since I must drop the EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE before dropping the CREDENTIAL.

I think that might be a bug of Azure SQLServer. Any idea how can I drop this properly and prevent this error happen in the future?

I can leave the hanging resource alone and creating a new one for my import but is it a good practice?

The error is also mention here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6e255ed0-21ad-4a52-b3b4-03fe94e05820/azure-sql-i-cant-drop-external-blobstorage-data-source-though-sysexternaltables-is-empty?forum=ssdsgetstarted
.But rescale the database or recreate it each time the error happens might be not a good idea.

**Edit**: I still didn't found the solution to this problem. But in my case, the ***external data source*** is hanging due to a mistake inside the FORMAT file (the one that defines the format of the import file, which I also store inside Azure Storage) I made while implementing new features. And even when I finally make the FORMAT file working correctly, the hanging ***external data source*** is still there and cannot be drop.

Comment: Did you try the solution mentioned in the same msdn link.. Which is scaling up and down ?

Comment: I tried it, didn't work in my case.  I found out that the error happens when my format file has some problem. Which cause the EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE being stuck and cannot be drop.

Comment: Great .! please provide your own answer,which might help someone in the future